# When a question is migrated, re-associate the comments when the user creates an account on the site

Tags: feature-request, migration

[A question on English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19563/is-the-truth-a-privative?noredirect=1) has been migrated on [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/is-the-truth-a-privative). When I noticed it, I created an account on that site, and my answer was associated with my account, but the comments I posted before the migration have not been associated with my account.

[image: screenshot]

The comments should be associated with the account, after I create one on the site where the question has been migrated.
I could have made comments that were pertinent on the previous site, and I could like to remove them; sometimes, I could just delete the old comment, and add a new comment that is more pertinent for the site where the question has been migrated.