# Comment authors are not getting migrated

Tags: bug, status-deferred, comments, migrated-questions

Background: when question is migrated from site A to site B and the author doesn't have account in site B, their name will appear "gray" until they log in to site B and associate the accounts, then the avatar show and all is good. No problems here, same for answers and their authors.

Problem: if user from site A posted **comments** while the question was still in site A, their name will stay gray and unclickable **even after they logs in and have account in site B**:

[image: Screenshot]

[This is the above question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121043), but most likely it's global problem, not specific to that one occurrence.

Comment: Nick already answered this elsewhere on meta, but basically comments don't contain enough user information for us to reliably map them in all situations.

Comment: @Jeff thanks, didn't see such answer. Isn't there user ID associated with each comment? Just the raw display name?

Comment: @Haney since you added the deferred tag, any updates about this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard none at this time. It's not critical and we're slammed at the moment, but one day we hope to investigate further. :)

Comment: @Haney thanks for the honest response!

Comment: @ShadowWizard all I can be really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When a question is migrated, re-associate the comments when the user creates an account on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110765/when-a-question-is-migrated-re-associate-the-comments-when-the-user-creates-an)

Comment: @CodyGray no. This one here got official response and a status tag, so if anything, it's the other way around.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Glorf and I closed it as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Ollie cheers, you get a golden monkey as reward. :P

Comment: @Mast Why the unnecessary bump?

Answer (score 14):

Here's the answer Jeff's referring to on why this doesn't happen currently:
[Comments by OP on migrated question become "anonymous"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68434/comments-by-op-on-migrated-question-become-anonymous/92991#92991)

We may revisit hooking up comments in the future, but it's not a completely trivial problem (e.g. should reply to hook up as well? that's more info that needs carrying over), and won't/can't be retroactive.  That being said, I do have an idea on how to take care of this in a not *terribly* expensive way, I'll throw it out to the team and see if it's worth it.

Comment: Cheers, good luck with that idea of yours - hope it will be accepted and implemented. :)

Comment: At the very least, could commenters be notified in some non-expensive way that the question is being or has been migrated?

Comment: Three years later, any update?

Comment: 9 years later, any update?

Comment: 10,5 years later, I don't even ask, lol.