# Comment author link not a link?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, hyperlinks, migrated-questions

On [this pro-webmasters question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/81676/6005), although the OP still has an active account (and the profile link in the question's flair renders normally), if you look at [some of the comments](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/firefox-accusing-me-of-distributing-malware-on-my-site#comment96972_81678) you'll see that the OP's name (and that of some others) is being rendered as plain text, as it would if the user had been deleted.

> [image: gimme rep for freehand circles]

What's going on here? Is it related to the fact that the question was migrated? Is it a bug?

At the very least I'd expect the OP's linkification to be consistent, across both pre-migration and post-migration content.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Good find; I think you're right. Ta :)

Comment: Cheers! By the way, you could have used a binding close vote by clicking the "I agree" in the dupe banner on top instead of voting to close in the old fashion way. :)

Comment: @Shadow: Huh never noticed that button. Pretty dumb that the two options do different things, then.

Comment: Someone just started a feature request just for those cases: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261430/confirming-that-my-own-question-is-a-duplicate-by-voting-to-close-should-have-im :-)

Comment: lol, [another innocent victim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264201/exclusively-excluding-tag-in-search-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment859848_264201)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> migrated from superuser.com yesterday

The key is in that. The OP has an active profile *now*, but didn't at the time of migration. When a poster follows their question to the destination site, we map it to their account. Comments, however, aren't mapped this way.

Comment: Perhaps they should be? This was quite confusing.

Comment: I agree that it can be confusing. However, we don't keep account id history on comments, so doing that is somewhere between impossible and error-prone (since usernames aren't unique). Combined with the fact that this is a rare case, and in many situations where this happens we don't care about *keeping* the comments in the first place... meh.

Comment: @AnnaLear I know that's it's pretty rare, but is there any plan on adding something simple like a tooltip saying `this question was migrated` or `this user did not have an account at the time of migration` on the username?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ No plans, no. I don't remember off-hand if we preserve display names on comments for users that were deleted... But other things could be in play as well - such as a question getting migrated and then migration history being removed.

Comment: @AnnaLear ok. At least there's a definite answer :)

Comment: @Anna no plans means [my earlier bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121052/comment-authors-are-not-getting-migrated) is also doomed? Good ol' Nick said "We may revisit hooking up comments in the future" but it was over three years ago...

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nick's answer sounds about right... but it's also about 3 years old now, so there's that...