# Exclusively excluding tag in search doesn't work

Tags: bug, tag-search

**Use case**
Excluding tags in search results using `-[tagname]`.

**Observed behaviour**
This goes as expected:

- Action: Search for anything *and* exclude a tag (for example `-[microsoft-excel] word` on SU)
- Result: posts are shown that don't have the [microsoft-excel] tag and that contain `word`.

But this doesn't:

- Action: Search exclusively all posts that *don't* have a specific tag (for example `-[microsoft-excel]` on SU).
- Action: Click "Newest" in the search results.
- Result: post that contain the tag [microsoft-excel] are shown and the search string is enclosed by double quotes (see pic below).

[image: Search results exclusively excluding a tag]

**Expected behaviour**
Searching exclusively excluding a tag shows all posts that don't have that tag, even if the tabs in the search results are switched.

Comment: Indeed! It's a dupe. Good find! I searched for it but couldn't find it. I flagged the question as a dupe.

Comment: Well, it wasn't tagged properly. You can close your own question in one click by clicking the "I agree" blue button in the banner you see on top of your question.