# Why are the authors of comments on very old meta posts not clickable?

Tags: bug, comments, per-site-meta, old-questions

Houston, we (The [Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)ers) faced a problem today, [revisiting](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4087995#4087995) this post on meta.SO: [What's the joke in the Stack Overflow 404 page code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code/252187#252187)

The accounts of none of the posters has been removed. Yet . . .

> Yes, there should be room, but since the 404 is an image, it would be somewhat difficult to convey whitespace :) – Mark Rushakoff [Nov 10 '09 at 23:19](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code/252187#comment6721_252187)

(There should be a link to @Mark's profile page, but there isn't)

This doesn't happen on meta.SO only. The comments on [Should personal computer-troubleshooting questions be asked on SF?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/52/should-personal-computer-troubleshooting-questions-be-asked-on-sf) on meta.SU aren't clickable either. However, [How to ask great questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/how-to-ask-great-questions)  (On meta.SE) doesn't suffer the same symptom.

The only thing the former two posts have in common is they're both very, very old, but the third post is also old. This could be the cause, but how? What has happened? Can it be fixed, please?

Comment: Yay you get a cookie

Comment: What do you mean "comments not clickable"? What you expect to happen when clicking a comment? For me, nothing ever happened. (unless the comment contains a link?)

Comment: @Sha I mean there should be a link to the author's profile, but there isn't. (Editing, please wait)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply because those users did not have account on the site in the time when the question was migrated. (As you can see, both questions you used as example have been migrated)

In ideal world, the comment author would have become clickable when creating account, but that's not the case and there is <s>an existing feature request asking to change this behavior</s> a [very old bug report about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121052/comment-authors-are-not-getting-migrated).

Comment: Thinking about it, it's a dupe. :/